# Setting combobox from another class

Tags: java, combobox

Is it possible to set the selected item of a combobox from a different class? Say I have Class A and Class B, in class A I setup the combobox and add it to the Jframe. Could I do something like ClassA.comboBox.setSelectedItem("Option1"); from class B? That doesn't work but I hope it illustrates what I am trying to do. Do you know how/if I can achieve this result with Java? Many thanks.

Comment: `setSelectedItem()` should work; please edit your question to include a [mcve] that shows your current approach.

Comment: First, any suggestion to use `static` is a dirty, dirty HACK and should be burnt to the ground. Next, you can pass a reference of `A` to `B` so `B` can call some method of `A` passing it the value it what's to be selected. The important point here, is you really, really want to restrict what `B` could to to `A`. The alternative would be to use a [Observer Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html) which would allow `A` to monitor `B` for possible changes and take appropriate action. This de-couples your code and makes it more re-usable in the long run

Answer (score 3):

This a common enough problem which can solved in several ways

## You could...

Pass a reference of `A` to `B`, so `B` can call what ever methods `A` has available to change it's state.

You should avoid allowing direct access to your classes fields, because it would allow `B` to do things you might not want it to do.

Equally, you should prefer `interface`s over passing actually implementations, further restricting what `B` can do to `A`.

This, however, does tighten the coupling of your code.  What should `A` have to have a reference to `B` to do anything (or visa-versa)

## You could...

Use an [Observer Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html), allowing `B` to generate events that interested parties (like `A`) so that they can update themselves accordingly, based on there own choices, the event and/or the state of `B`

This de-couples your code (`B` no longer needs an instance of `A` to do anything) and makes your code more re-usable, other classes can register interest with instances `B` and `B` doesn't care

## You shouldn't...

Use `static`.  `static` is a BAD, BAD idea when it comes to cross communication between objects.  The moment you have more then one instance of any class, the whole thing just blows up into a horrible mess.  You also lose a lot of control over who is doing what to those instances (nothing stopping any one from creating a new instance of a class and assigning it to the `static` field), all of which just makes your life a misery (or in the case of the developers who have to clean it up, your name becomes a dirty word)

Answer (score 0):

If you have an instance of A in B the better option is to have getters/setters for the elements you need in A :

```
Class A {
    private JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();

    public A(){}
    public JCombobox getComboBox(){ return comboBox;}
}
```

And in B :

```
Class B {
    public B(){
    A aInstance = new A();
    aInstance.getComboBox().setSelectedItem("Option1");
}
```

Comment: *"First, any suggestion to use static is a dirty, dirty HACK and should be burnt to the ground"*  - Please, please, PLEASE stop suggesting `static` as a solution for cross class communication, it is NOT the solution for this problem.  Instead, either pass a reference of `A` to `B` (not fantastic) or use an [Observer Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html) so `B` can tell `A` when it wants something changed

Answer (score 0):

You can first create the class `B` and then pass the reference `A` to the class `B`, then in the class `B` you can do what you want with class `A`. A simple example:

```
class A extends JFrame {

    private ComboBox comboBox;

    public A() {
      comboBox = new ComboBox();
      B b = new B(this);
    }

    public void addItem(Obejct item) {
        // add item to comboBox
    }

}

class B {
    private A a;

    public B(A a) {
         this.a = a;
         String item = "new Item";
         a.addItem(item);
    }

}
```

Hope this help!